# How to get your question answered if it is not bountied

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401356/stripe-invalidrequesterror-invalidrequesterror-at-payment-stripe-request-req-5) question about invalid stripe parameters which for me is really important, and I desperately need to solve it, to complete the project.

Although it got 30+ views, there was no answer to help me solve my problem. The question has long since become buried by newer questions, and there's still no accepted answer. I just wanted to know, how to grab attention of readers except bounties, because for a new user like me, it's not possible to offer bounties. I admit I asked a question that was a bit more difficult to answer.

After waiting for some time, I received no answers, little or no comments, and only a few views. The question does show up in the "unanswered" list, but no one has answered my question.

In either case, what's the protocol for me to try to get this question answered?

Comment: Just don't [repost the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346997/158100) across the network, ever.

Comment: You don't "get" the right to an answer, you get the right to *post your question* and show it to the world. For free! Valid alternatives are: post it on a for-pay site (although you need to read their site rules carefully; you may still not be *entitled* to an answer), or earn enough reputation here by asking and answering good questions to put a bounty on this one. (Which also is not a solid guarantee – but at least it will attract more views.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've had some advice, I suggest you address it. Use your browser's developer tools to see if the browser is posting the token to you/stripe/wherever. Use the console to check for JavaScript errors. Set breakpoints and step your JavaScript and check it's all going correctly.

You have had some interest to your question, people (a person) have suggested things. Follow up on their suggestions, debug, and add more information to your question. Keep them engaged by talking with them and giving them more information to feed their curiosity.

I'm a lot more interested to answer people's questions when they engage with me and give me information that I ask for or do more work, and provide more information that shows my suggestion isn't a problem and I can think of something else.

No one but you will be as invested in this, but you can do more to keep people working with you (your final comment only repeats what you already said, it adds nothing).

Answer (score 10):

> It was supposed to be a platform where people would help others

Well, it is supposed to be a platform where people ***who know the answer*** would ***voluntarily*** help others.

You can't make people who don't have an answer magically provide a solution. And you can't *force* people to answer your question if they're not interested. All you can do is make sure that your question follows the guidelines shown in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (e.g., well-formatted, concise but complete, clear enough, and that the problem is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

After that, I'm afraid you just have to wait. As a rule of thumb, if you're not paying for a service, you can't *demand* a result. People are volunteering to help (when they can and when they want to). That's what "volunteering" means. Just be a little bit patient. People are not as active at the weekend.

> because for a new user like me, it's not possible to offer bounties

Note that even for users with plenty of reputation, one still can't offer a bounty until after 48 hours from the time the question was posted.

Comment: Yes I completely understand that not everyone can answer and that people here are volunteering to help, [ I thank them wholeheartedly ] but, even after following guidelines, being patient, the question seems to fade away

Comment: Being patient is 6 to 8 weeks, not 6 to 8 hours ....

Comment: @rene I always see you commenting about this meme everywhere. You probably have a world record by now :-D

Comment: If you really-really-really need an answer to your questions, then there are several sites where you can find freelancers for any size tasks. Post your question there and be ready to leave some money.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Hah! One of my managers once said "it will be done in 6 to 8 weeks" to a customer and I couldn't hold it laughing out loud ...  so yeah, that one is special to me.